# Add trusted CA to ubuntu without ca-certificates package

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ssl-certificate, apt, self-signed

**Problem:**

- I want to build a docker container `FROM:ubuntu:20.04` but I do not have access to the outside internet
- I have an apt mirror on the internal network that I can use
- apt mirror is behind https with a custom certificate
- I have the CA for the custom certificate
- the basic `ubuntu:20.04` container does not have `ca-certificates` package, so I do not have the `update-ca-certificates` command available

**What I did so far:**

- run the container (`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash  ubuntu:20.04`)
- in the container, wiped the apt list and replaced it with my custom apt repos

  ```
   echo > /etc/apt/sources.list
   echo 'deb https://mycompany.internal.network/ubuntu-remote focal main restricted' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   echo 'deb https://mycompany.internal.network/ubuntu-remote focal multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   echo 'deb https://mycompany.internal.network/ubuntu-remote focal universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   [.....]
  ```
- placed the root CA for https in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycompany/`

From here, IF I COULD I would just run `update-ca-certificates` and everything would work. I tested that by installing the `ca-certificates` package before hand, but in the correct CI workflow in which this container will be created, there is no access to the ubuntu upstream apt so I cannot do that, and this will be rebuilt periodically to keep the image up to date.
**How do I make it trust the internal repo without using `update-ca-certificates`?** All the articles I find point to doing that, but I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

### There are actually two possibilities that come to my mind.

The *simplest*, but **most dangerous** approach would be to simply *disable certificate verification*.

The *more mature* and **secure solution** would be to *provide the necessary Debian package archive(s)* for installing `ca-certificates` manually.

#### Disable certificate verification

You can achieve this via an additional option to apt itself, either for any or specific hosts. The *APT option* you are looking for is `Acquire::https::Verify-Peer` for any host or `Acquire::https::<host>::Verify-Peer` just for a specific host. Since *disabling host verification for any host is **even temporarily** a potential dangerous act*, I would suggest to go with the host specific variant - nevertheless you really shall know which registry hosts you have set in your `sources.list` file. Given your example, the command looks like follows.

```
apt-get -o Acquire::https::mycompany.internal.network::Verify-Peer=0 update
```

Since this sets the option only temporarily during this one invocation, you also have to set it when actually installing something (probably "ca-certificates") like follows:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::https::mycompany.internal.network::Verify-Peer=0 install ca-certificates
```

You could also set this option permanently in [apt.conf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/apt.conf.5.html) but I strongly discourage this approach (especially the host unspecific variant), since it would permanently disable HTTPS host verification (for one or even any host) completely - as long as the option resides within your apt.conf.

#### Provide the necessary Debian package archive(s)

This solution is not "as easy" as the first one, but is definitely the one to prefer regarding integrity and is actually not really much more difficult. What you would basically do is, you get the Debian package archive (*.deb) for `ca-certificates` and also for its dependencies, copy them over to your docker container and install them via `dpkg`.

While the first step (getting the Debian package archive (`.deb`) for `ca-certificates`) seems and also is fairly easy, getting all of its *required* dependencies is a more difficult task - at least if you do not have an equivalent "target operating system", i.e. Ubuntu 20.04. But if you do have, you could basically just run the following command to download all `.deb` for installing a particular package into the current working directory.

```
apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances ca-certificates | grep "^\w")
```

You can then either copy the files into the container during `docker build` or bind mount them later - either way you would want to simply (try to) install all of them by changing into the directory containing all the `.deb` files in the container context and issue:

```
dpkg -i *
```

`dpkg` will probably note that some packages are already installed and skip those.

Like already mentioned, this only works properly if the target container operating system matches the operating system where the packages are being downloaded. If this is not the case, you could basically just resolve and download package dependencies manually via the [Ubuntu package registry index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

### Conclusion

Regardless of the chosen solution, you will finally get a working installation for `ca-certificates`.